# How do sure that the annotation processor is always applied to all annotated elements?

Tags: java, annotation-processing

I wrote custom annotation processor, which collects all the annotated classes, organizes them lexicographical and generates a new class for each annotated class.

In Intellij Idea, when the project is incrementally built, **not all** annotated classes from project are passed to my annotation processor, **but only those that have been modified/added**.
This violates the ordering logic.

How do I make sure that the annotation processor is always applied to all annotated elements on each build?

I found it article also, but seems that it work onl with Gradle: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:incremental_annotation_processing

Is it possible to make annotation processor to aggregate incremental for any build tool?

Is it possible to make **such** annotation processor to isolate incremental?

Source code of my annotation processor: https://github.com/ElegantNetworking/ElegantNetworkingAnnotationProcessor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're asking the wrong question. Here's the thought process that lead you to asking the wrong question:

1. Hmm, my AP only sees a handful of all the source code on a compile run, that's odd! This leads to bugs, and I want to fix these bugs.
2. Oh, wait, I get it, it's because of incremental compilation.
3. I know! I'll disable incremental compilation!
4. Hmm, so how do I do that? I better ask SO.

I'll give a direct answer first, but you're not going to like it: You basically can't. Re-compiling the entire codebase everytime the system wants to compile is incredibly inefficient; nobody likes it when a single simple change in a source file then results in having to wait 250 seconds to see the effect of this. You'd soon blame the tools (be it gradle or intellij) for being incredibly hostile to your productive hours. The tools know this, and will not (easily) allow such an innocent act (such as including some annotation processor) to make the tool borderline unusable.

You also don't want to find out how to 'fix' this, because, well, I did just say 'borderline unusable'. You surely don't *want* your turnaround time on a change to go from half a second to 5 minutes.

There *is* a good solution though - but only if you go back a few steps.

The thing about incremental compilation is: The things that aren't being compiled (because they did not change / do not need to be)? They *WERE* compiled earlier. All you need to do is follow along: Just like compiling a source file produces a result that is 'persistent', and implies you don't need to redo it until some condition occurs that indicates you need to re-apply the process, you need to do the same thing with your AP: If some source file is processed by your AP, that needs to leave a persistent effect; that effect needs to be enough for all future runs **without** the benefit of having the original source tree, at least until said source tree is changed.

This is easier than it seems, because you have the filer.

I'm going to describe an Annotation Processor as an example:

This processor will scan for all types annotated with `@Provides(com.pkg.Foo.class)`, checks if the type so annotated does implement or extend `Foo`, and then makes a file `META-INF/services/com.pkg.Foo`, listing the type in there. This describes, exactly, how an SPI processor works: It's what [google's auto-service processor](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/service) does, for example (there are a bunch of such projects around).

This process is trivial for a full compile run: The AP can just make a `Map<String, List<String>>` that maps e.g. `"com.pkg.Foo"` to `["com.company.FooImpl1", "com.company.FooImpl2"]`, filling it up as rounds occur and as source files are visited, and then during the end round, dump these maps out in the form of service files. The AP is like 2 pages worth of codes, nearly trivial, and yet quite useful.

The problem is, that model does not actually work out when incremental compilation occurs: in an incremental compile run, only `FooImpl1` is spotted, the map thus maps `Foo` only to `FooImpl1`, and when it is time to dump the file out the disk, `FooImpl2` just disappeared from your services file, even though the FooImpl2 class is still around - it was simply not in the incremental compile run as it wasn't changed.

The solution is simple, though: You have a filer!

Instead of just dumping each of these built-up maps into the services file and calling it a day, you need to **read** the services file first. If it's not there, easy enough, just go back to the 'dump the list out' code. But if it **is** there, read every entry in it, ask the filer for these classes. If the filer cannot find one of these, then remove the line from the services file. If it can, keep it.

Okay, so now our AP has gone from maybe 2 pages to 3 pages, but it is now completely capable of following along with incremental compilation. It can tell the difference between someone deleting `FooImpl2` and doing a full recompile (which should result in a services file containing only `FooImpl1`), and someone first doing a full run (resulting in both 1 and 2 being in the services file), and then changing only FooImpl1.java and doing an incremental compile run:

```
class MyProcessor extends javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor {
  @Override public void init(ProcessingEnvironment env) {
    // you need these:
    Filer filer = env.getFiler();
    Elements elementUtils = processingEnv.getElementUtils();
  }
}
```

with the filer, you can do:

```
  FileObject resource = filer.getResource(StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT,
  "", pathToServicesFile);
```

and from there you can read that file (if it is there), to check which classes are already in that services file: In your incremental compile run, this would give you `com.company.FooImpl1` and `com.company.FooImpl2`. You can then check if these types (still) exist:

```
elements.getTypeElement("com.company.FooImpl1")
```

if that returns `null`, it no longer exists, and you can strip it from your services file. If it does, keep it - unless you hit that file doing your rounds and it turns out it's no longer annotated. The point is: If you never hit that file, at all, during your rounds, that means it was excluded because the incremental compilation process did not consider it changed, and therefore, the last known state (which is that `FooImpl1` implements `Foo` and is annotated with `@Provides(Foo.class)`, hence why it is in the already existing services file) is still correct, so, act accordingly.

If the output/effect of your annotation processor does not include anything that could possibly be used to figure it out on a later incremental compile run, then **make such a file**: Make a file that 'tracks' the state you do need to know about.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for such complete answer, Rzwitserloot.
I meant that I want that my annotation processor to be able to see all classes marked with my annotation, because a generated classes are based on all classes that are annotated.
It is my understanding that annotation processor should be aggregate incremental.
I didn’t mention the term "aggregate incremental" because I’m not sure if this is exactly what I need.
I improved the question a little to make it look clearer.

It's a good idea to use a file with lists of previously processed elements to consider all the elements in the project

Comment: _be able to see all classes marked with my annotation_ - well, you can't. I hope that part was clear from my answer. You can fake it by using the filer to write a file that lists everything you saw in earlier compile runs, and use the `getTypeElement` code as I showed in the example to ensure that those types still exist. This _is_ exactly what you need. Or, I hope so, because if it is not, the answer is a much simpler single word: __impossible__.

Comment: Well. This means that the aggregate incremental compilation is purely a feature of Gradle.
.
.
.

When I use `getTypeElement` with name of element which not exists in current compilation(already compiled, not changed still), it return `null`. Does that mean I need to verify existence of element by checking the file's existence, right?

Comment: @hohserg doublecheck that - gTE should absolutely return stuff, even if not in this incremental compilation.

Comment: Ok, I tried this approach and obtained follow experience: my annotation processor does not called anyway when class with annotation has been removed. I continue testing in Idea. Do I need to create an another question topic?

Comment: Yes, when a file is removed, the class file(s) affected are removed and the compiler isn't even started. This is lightly annoying. However, using the filer trick, if _ANY_ source file is compiled for any reason, your AP runs and can use the filer to figure out it needs to delete a few lines. That is now only a minor inconvenience (recompile something. anything - the AP will run and see that one of the source files is now gone), and as far as I know, cannot be eliminated.

Comment: Ok, thx. Excess classes is not sensitive for my task, but it really annoying, haha) ```as far as I know, cannot be eliminated``` I tried to run javac from command line with no classes for compilation and he didn't run AP. But Idea possible can use some trick: recompile some one class if no classes need to compile and least one class was been removed, it must give a way to correct generated files of APs. I think that it may be a good feature request for Idea if add a bit of details, like class choice principle for recompilation

Comment: I'm stumped. I have a follow cases: 1) annotated class changed, annotation stay => AP#init and AP#process called, so need to write service file at last AP#process call. 2)annotated class changed, annotation removed => only AP#init called, so need to write service file at AP#init call. 3)annotated class changed, annotation removed, and added new annotated class => AP#init and AP#process called, so need do similar with first case. I signs that need to discern this cases at AP#init call. How to do it?

Comment: I can discern 1) and 2) by checking annotations at element, but I can't imagine discern 1) and 3). And I can't write service file twice because each output file must be created and written once

Comment: At init, use the filer, and read the metadata you wrote in earlier compilations about what file(s) existed back then (i.e. your SPI file, if it's an SPI generator). Then, at end, combine that data + a bunch of calls to the filer to check which files existed + all stuff you picked up during rounds to rewrite the file. In case only init() and last round is called, then what you'll be doing is reading the file, then checking each entry via Filer, and rewriting the entries that are still existing.

Comment: The fact is that there is a case exists which is called ONLY init, without last round

Comment: Yup, that sounds annoying. You can make a timer, or just write the file during init (after using filer to check AND confirming that you have an update to make), and then again after the rounds, that's.. not too much of a bother; you're writing twice where you could have gotten away with writing once, but, that's within reason, no?

Comment: Yes, it's may be a solve, but it's look as a bad design. Uhh, what is wrong with this compiler? Thanks for your advices, it helps a lot psychologically